# How can I run a program remotely via SSH but display locally

Tags: linux, ssh, x-server

Is it possible for me to SSH to another server in Linux (Ubuntu), run a program there but display it locally?

And is it possible for me to SSH to another server in my terminal,
and configure it so that all graphical programs (Firefox, Emacs) run in that SSH session will be displayed locally?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

By adding the "-Y" flag to the ssh command, the display will automatically be redirected to your local computer.

```
ssh -Y <remoteip>
```

Then, if you start Firefox (or any other X application) in that ssh session, it will be displayed locally. (If you have a xserver running locally of course)

Comment: I will use `-X` since this way forwarding is subjected to `X11 SECURITY`. But if you trust the remote machine then you can use `-Y`.

Comment: Under Unixes like HP UX 11i, -Y is the way to go due to incompatibility issues with -X.

Comment: does this work when the remote machine is Windows? I can get it to display.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking to do remote X.  This is a [good mini HOWTO](http://www.xs4all.nl/~zweije/xauth.html).

Comment: err, not for anything headless that does not have X.  htop for example.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use compression when using X-forwarding:

```
ssh $HOSTNAME -CY $PROCESS
```

Answer (score 3):

You might also want to try this:

```
ssh <hostname> -X <program-name or its full path>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another option which is usually more desirable. X11-forwarding is still kinda slow and the programs crash when your wifi connection just dropped AGAIN. With my [remote-work](https://github.com/tycho-kirchner/remote-work) project you can configure any app, say gedit, to open the file with a **local** gedit-instance from **within the ssh session**. All you have to do is add `REMOTE_EXEC_PRODUCER_ADD_APPS gedit` in the remote bashrc, enter `gedit foo` and the gedit installed on your laptop will open the remote file via sshfs. See also https://github.com/tycho-kirchner/remote-work