# How can I see (on my local display) emacs (and other graphical apps) running on a VPS?

Tags: ssh, emacs, vps, x-server

[Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22275012/what-should-i-set-the-display-environmental-variable-to?noredirect=1#comment33846236_22275012) posted on StackOverflow by mistake.

The VPS is running CentOS 6.x

It looks like [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/123765/how-can-i-run-a-program-remotely-via-ssh-but-display-locally) is highly relevant, but neither -Y nor -X worked. (As an I do trust the remote server, but always prefer the tighter security if possible.)

In response to Richard E. Silverman's help on the original post, I'm listing the output of -vv below:

```
$ssh [redacted]@[redacted] -X -p [redacted] -vv
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to [redacted].
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/[redacted]/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/[redacted]/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/[redacted]/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/[redacted]/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 130/256
debug2: bits set: 506/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA [redacted]
debug1: checking without port identifier
debug1: Host '[redacted]' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/[redacted]/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: found matching key w/out port
debug2: bits set: 520/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /Users/[redacted]/.ssh/id_rsa (0x0),
debug2: key: /Users/[redacted]/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/[redacted]/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/[redacted]/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
[redacted]'s password: 
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to [redacted]).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: Checking for xauth using /opt/X11/bin/xauth -f /var/folders/vx/7dvtlfhn0zqcnpqsg2894_n00000gq/T//xauth_test exit > /dev/null 2> /dev/null

debug2: x11_get_proto: /opt/X11/bin/xauth -f /var/folders/vx/7dvtlfhn0zqcnpqsg2894_n00000gq/T//ssh-6ZqGmD9RTF6q/xauthfile generate /tmp/launch-ZMvHpM/org.macosforge.xquartz:0 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 untrusted timeout 1200 2>/dev/null
debug2: x11_get_proto: /opt/X11/bin/xauth -f /var/folders/vx/7dvtlfhn0zqcnpqsg2894_n00000gq/T//ssh-6ZqGmD9RTF6q/xauthfile list /tmp/launch-ZMvHpM/org.macosforge.xquartz:0 2>/dev/null
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug2: channel 0: request x11-req confirm 1
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug1: Remote: No xauth program; cannot forward with spoofing.
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 100 id 0
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Last login: Sun Mar  9 09:41:12 2014 from [redacted]
```

I do NOT believe I have xauth installed, so I will try fixing that first...

Comment: xauth was not installed. After installing it (with sudo yum install xauth), I was able to view emacs (and presumably other graphical applications) on my local host. (Will come back and 'answer' the question after 10 hours if no one beats me to it.)

Comment: So actually, now the fonts are stopping the show for me: Pango-WARNING **: failed to choose a font, expect ugly output. engine-type='PangoRenderFc', script='latin'. Even thought I can see the text in emacs itself, the window title is just a bunch of squares. In another application, an entire dialog box is just squares...